# How to mock single function in Swift?

Tags: unit-testing, swift, mocking

My question is simple, how to mock a function (not a method) in Swift.
i.e., a standalone function not inside of a class.

Thank you.

EDIT:

Let's say I have the following function:

```
func distance(c1: CLLocation, c2: CLLocation) {
    ...
}
```

And I want to test my class:

```
class MyClass {

    func selectedLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        let text = "\(distance(self.currentLocation, location)) meters"

        self.view.showText(text)
    }

}
```

How do I mock the `distance` function?

Answer (score 1):

To mock the distance function, you would need to do something like this

```
func distance(c1: CLLocation, c2: CLLocation) -> CLLocationDistance {
  // ...
}

class MyClass {
  var calculateDistance = distance

  func selectedLocation(location: CLLocation) {
    let text = "\(calculateDistance(self.currentLocation, location)) meters"

    self.view.showText(text)
  }

}
```

And in your test code you would need to do this:

```
func testCalculateDistanceFromLocation() {
  let thing = MyClass()
  thing.calculateDistance = { c1, c2 in /* return mock distance here */ }

  // assert correct text appeared in the view
}
```

This way you are providing a new implementation of the distance function when in a testing environment. As far as I know you cannot completely replace the body of a top level function dynamically such that you don't need the internal class property that stores that function value.

This is kind of cumbersome though to do this for all your functions, so I say to only do this when you feel you absolutely need to substitute this extra mocked dependency. If possible, I would encourage you to test your class as a wnole unit, if it has few or no other external dependencies and treat the distance function as an implementation detail.

Comment: O updated my question to be more specific to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Do not know if I understand this correct. Swift does support global functions.

```
[update: This is what I do in the unit test]

    public func getNumber()->Int //add public for unit testing
    {
        return 1
    }

    class MyClass: NSObject
    {
        func calculate()
        {
            let num = getNumber()
            println(num)
        }
    }

///unit test case
    import MyModule

    extension NSObject
    {
         public fund getNumber()->Int
         {
             return 5 //mock implementation
         }
    }


    func testExample() {

        let myInstance = MyClass()
        myInstance.calculate()

    }
```

Comment: Yes, but how do you mock that global function for unit tests?

Comment: See my update for unit testing. In your main target, Build Settings -> Defines Module -> YES

Comment: The key is to add public accessor

Comment: I still don't get it how you mock the getNumber() function

Comment: When you said mock, I thought you experience challenges calling the standalone function in the unit tests. If it is incorrect, correct me. When I call this function in my unit tests, I added "public" in front of "func" and this function returns me the correct value. So when you call the "distance" method as you put in the code on top, do you have any compiling errors or runtime errors?

Comment: That is incorrect, I don't have problems calling the existing function in my unit tests. What I want to do is mock that function, i.e., give it a mock implementation.

Comment: I see. The only way I thought of so far is using an extension to NSObject in my unit test file, thus I can overwrite the original method. I need to make the original class extend NSObject too. I modified the post with the sample code. I tried to use runtime API to replace the global function but failed to access the global function at runtime.